# Who said "Don't believe history less than 50 years old"?

Tags: north-america

I remember reading a quote a little while that went something like "Don't trust history written less than fifty years after the event."

Who said this, and what was the exact quote, and the context? My recollection is that it was attributed to Richard Nixon, but I can't find any reference.

Comment: Did you read it from a source attributing it to Nixon before 2020? :-)

Comment: It was probably an idiot. Or clearly someone who has no clue how history works.

Comment: I don't know if it was Nixon, but it is something I've heard more than once, even from professors in high school.

The reason given is that in 50 years there are still living people first hand experience, with all the biases that impact on the consideration and analysis of actual fact. 50 years is a kind of "grace period" to be able to see in a more unbiased view.
To this consideration you can add that many state documents gets released to public after at least 30 years (like in uk - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-year_rule )

Comment: many state files wait 50 or 75 years before declassification (and there may be issues with that...). Even then, it will take years (or decades) until somebody study and compile them into mainstream books.  2 examples: Rommel's death was only explained after docs were opened, the previous current version was propaganda BS - I have old books with the old version; After soviet files were opened, they exposed McCarthy was often (not always) right. Governments or compromised individuals often get together to build the mainstream version.